# firebase rules how to make user can read only his data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I use firebase 8.10.0 white Vue Js.

I use only Google as a provider for authentication and I want user to read-only his data, so i use `firestore rules`:

my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /users/{id} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == id;
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

and this is how i get the data:

```
...

let ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users");

// .where("__name__", "==", uid) or
ref.doc(uid).get().then((doc) => {
  this.data = [{id: doc.id}];
})
// working well

ref.get().then((doc) => {
  doc.forEach((doc) => {
    this.data.push({ id: doc.id });
  });
})
// err: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

...
```

can I do this and ? how can i fix that? : my bad :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to query the whole `users` collections but your security rules allow a user to read a document with user's UID as doc ID. Security rules don't filter out documents so if you are trying to get current user's document only then try using `get()` on a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference):

```
// add .doc(<userId>)
let ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(currentUserId);

ref.get().then((doc) => {
  this.data = [{id: doc.id}];
})
```

Comment: What if i want user to only write his own data ... i am trying to do this [rules-conditions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication)

Comment: @Adam `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == id;` this should allow users to read/write/delete their own data only.

Comment: This is what I wrote but it doesn't work

Comment: @Adam can you explain "it doesn't work"? Like what operation are you trying to perform? Can you add that in your question? Also are you sure the user ID logged (you can confirm this by logging user's UID right before the read/write op)